# How to set vue chartjs begin at zero?

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

i have horizontalBar from chartjs using vue, i want to set the scale to begin with zero, i already add this code inside my options

```
scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              min: 0,
            }
          }]
        },
        scaleBeginAtZero : true,
```

but it doesn't work out.

```
data() {
    return {
      data: {
        labels: this.listLabel,
        datasets: [{
          label: "Usage",
          backgroundColor: "#41946E",
          data: this.listData
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: { 
          display: false,

        },
        label:{
          display: true
        },
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
            stacked: true,
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              min: 0,
            }
          }]
        },
        scaleBeginAtZero : true,


      }
    }
  },
```

i want it to look like this https://ibb.co/nPfmbDf, but i got it like this https://ibb.co/z7D2tP4 as you can see, Device 5 has 10 as a value but it showed no bar.

Answer (score 0):

write that inside options.

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Here is the link https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html from Chartjs